# Set fixed width to Nivo Slider

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I've installed Nivo Slider using the code from the demo included in the free download.

All of the images I am including in the slider are 800 pixels wide.

However, they are being resized to 1440 pixels wide.  Extra code is being inserted:

```
<img src="images/bar.jpg" data-thumb="images/bar.jpg" alt="" title="" style="display: none; width: 1440px;">
```

I have searched the CSS and JS and can find no mention of 1440.

Where is this width being set?

Answer (score 7):

Nivo Slider is responsive by default, if you want to limit the sliders width, use the below class in your CSS

```
.slider-wrapper.theme-default {
   width: 800px; /* Desired width */
}
```

---

The above will work if you are using `default` theme of nivo slider, if you are using some other theme, than simply change the `.theme-default` to theme specific `class` which is assigned to the slider wrapper.

Comment: Do you also know how to fix height and width at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use my custom nivo script code

/*
 * jQuery Nivo Slider v2.5.1
 * http://nivo.dev7studios.com
 *
 * Copyright 2011, Gilbert Pellegrom
 * Free to use and abuse under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * March 2010
 */

(function($) {
    var NivoSlider = function(element, options) {
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults, options);
        var vars = {
            currentSlide : 0,
            currentImage : '',
            totalSlides : 0,
            randAnim : '',
            running : false,
            paused : false,
            stop : false
        };
        var slider = $(element);
        slider.data('nivo:vars', vars);
        slider.css('position', 'relative');
        slider.addClass('nivoSlider');
        var kids = slider.children();
        kids.each(function() {
            var child = $(this);
            var link = '';
            if (!child.is('img')) {
                if (child.is('a')) {
                    child.addClass('nivo-imageLink');
                    link = child;
                }
                child = child.find('img:first');
            }
            var childWidth = child.width();
            if (childWidth == 0)
                childWidth = child.attr('width');
            var childHeight = child.height();
            if (childHeight == 0)
                childHeight = child.attr('height');
            if (childWidth > slider.width()) {
                slider.width(childWidth);
            }
            if (childHeight > slider.height()) {
                slider.height(childHeight);
            }
            if (link != '') {
                link.css('display', 'none');
            }
            child.css('display', 'none');
            vars.totalSlides++;
        });
        if (settings.startSlide > 0) {
            if (settings.startSlide >= vars.totalSlides)
                settings.startSlide = vars.totalSlides - 1;
            vars.currentSlide = settings.startSlide;
        }
        if ($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')) {
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
        } else {
            vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
        }
        if ($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')) {
            $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display', 'block');
        }
        slider.css({
            'background' : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat',
            'background-size' : settings.backgroundSize 
        });
        slider.append($('<div class="nivo-caption"><p></p></div>').css({
            display : 'none',
            opacity : settings.captionOpacity
        }));
        var processCaption = function(settings) {
            var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
            if (vars.currentImage.attr('title') != '') {
                var title = vars.currentImage.attr('title');
                if (title.substr(0, 1) == '#')
                    title = $(title).html();
                if (nivoCaption.css('display') == 'block') {
                    nivoCaption.find('p').fadeOut(settings.animSpeed, function() {
                        $(this).html(title);
                        $(this).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
                    });
                } else {
                    nivoCaption.find('p').html(title);
                }
                nivoCaption.fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
            } else {
                nivoCaption.fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);
            }
        }
        processCaption(settings);
        var timer = 0;
        if (!settings.manualAdvance && kids.length > 1) {
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false);
            }, settings.pauseTime);
        }
        if (settings.directionNav) {
            slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">' + settings.prevText + '</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">' + settings.nextText + '</a></div>');
            if (settings.directionNavHide) {
                $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                slider.hover(function() {
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
                }, function() {
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                });
            }
            $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function() {
                if (vars.running)
                    return false;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                vars.currentSlide -= 2;
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
            });
            $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function() {
                if (vars.running)
                    return false;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
            });
        }
        if (settings.controlNav) {
            var nivoControl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
            slider.append(nivoControl);
            for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
                if (settings.controlNavThumbs) {
                    var child = kids.eq(i);
                    if (!child.is('img')) {
                        child = child.find('img:first');
                    }
                    if (settings.controlNavThumbsFromRel) {
                        nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="' + i + '"><img src="' + child.attr('rel') + '" alt="" /></a>');
                    } else {
                        nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="' + i + '"><img src="' + child.attr('src').replace(settings.controlNavThumbsSearch, settings.controlNavThumbsReplace) + '" alt="" /></a>');
                    }
                } else {
                    nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="' + i + '">' + (i + 1) + '</a>');
                }
            }
            $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq(' + vars.currentSlide + ')', slider).addClass('active');
            $('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).live('click', function() {
                if (vars.running)
                    return false;
                if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
                    return false;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
                slider.css({
                    'background' : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat',
                    'background-size' : settings.backgroundSize 
                });
                vars.currentSlide = $(this).attr('rel') - 1;
                nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
            });
        }
        if (settings.keyboardNav) {
            $(window).keypress(function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == '37') {
                    if (vars.running)
                        return false;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                    vars.currentSlide -= 2;
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
                }
                if (event.keyCode == '39') {
                    if (vars.running)
                        return false;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
                }
            });
        }
        if (settings.pauseOnHover) {
            slider.hover(function() {
                vars.paused = true;
                clearInterval(timer);
                timer = '';
            }, function() {
                vars.paused = false;
                if (timer == '' && !settings.manualAdvance) {
                    timer = setInterval(function() {
                        nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false);
                    }, settings.pauseTime);
                }
            });
        }
        slider.bind('nivo:animFinished', function() {
            vars.running = false;
            $(kids).each(function() {
                if ($(this).is('a')) {
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
            if ($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')) {
                $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display', 'block');
            }
            if (timer == '' && !vars.paused && !settings.manualAdvance) {
                timer = setInterval(function() {
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false);
                }, settings.pauseTime);
            }
            settings.afterChange.call(this);
        });
        var createSlices = function(slider, settings, vars) {
            for (var i = 0; i < settings.slices; i++) {
                var sliceWidth = Math.round(slider.width() / settings.slices);
                if (i == settings.slices - 1) {
                    slider.append($('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({
                        left : (sliceWidth * i) + 'px',
                        width : (slider.width() - (sliceWidth * i)) + 'px',
                        height : '0px',
                        opacity : '0',
                        background : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat -' + ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) + 'px 0%',
                        'background-size': settings.backgroundSize 
                    }));
                } else {
                    slider.append($('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({
                        left : (sliceWidth * i) + 'px',
                        width : sliceWidth + 'px',
                        height : '0px',
                        opacity : '0',
                        background : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat -' + ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) + 'px 0%',
                        'background-size': settings.backgroundSize 
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
        var createBoxes = function(slider, settings, vars) {
            var boxWidth = Math.round(slider.width() / settings.boxCols);
            var boxHeight = Math.round(slider.height() / settings.boxRows);
            for (var rows = 0; rows < settings.boxRows; rows++) {
                for (var cols = 0; cols < settings.boxCols; cols++) {
                    if (cols == settings.boxCols - 1) {
                        slider.append($('<div class="nivo-box"></div>').css({
                            opacity : 0,
                            left : (boxWidth * cols) + 'px',
                            top : (boxHeight * rows) + 'px',
                            width : (slider.width() - (boxWidth * cols)) + 'px',
                            height : boxHeight + 'px',
                            background : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat -' + ((boxWidth + (cols * boxWidth)) - boxWidth) + 'px -' + ((boxHeight + (rows * boxHeight)) - boxHeight) + 'px',
                            'background-size': settings.backgroundSize 
                        }));
                    } else {
                        slider.append($('<div class="nivo-box"></div>').css({
                            opacity : 0,
                            left : (boxWidth * cols) + 'px',
                            top : (boxHeight * rows) + 'px',
                            width : boxWidth + 'px',
                            height : boxHeight + 'px',
                            background : 'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat -' + ((boxWidth + (cols * boxWidth)) - boxWidth) + 'px -' + ((boxHeight + (rows * boxHeight)) - boxHeight) + 'px',
                            'background-size': settings.backgroundSize 
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var nivoRun = function(slider, kids, settings, nudge) {
            var vars = slider.data('nivo:vars');
            if (vars && (vars.currentSlide == vars.totalSlides - 1)) {
                settings.lastSlide.call(this);
            }
            if ((!vars || vars.stop) && !nudge)
                return false;
            settings.beforeChange.call(this);
            if (!nudge) {
                slider.css({'background':'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat','background-size': settings.backgroundSize });
            } else {
                if (nudge == 'prev') {
                    slider.css({'background':'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat','background-size': settings.backgroundSize });
                }
                if (nudge == 'next') {
                    slider.css({'background':'url("' + vars.currentImage.attr('src') + '") no-repeat','background-size': settings.backgroundSize });
                }
            }
            vars.currentSlide++;
            if (vars.currentSlide == vars.totalSlides) {
                vars.currentSlide = 0;
                settings.slideshowEnd.call(this);
            }
            if (vars.currentSlide < 0)
                vars.currentSlide = (vars.totalSlides - 1);
            if ($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')) {
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
            } else {
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
            }
            if (settings.controlNav) {
                $('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).removeClass('active');
                $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq(' + vars.currentSlide + ')', slider).addClass('active');
            }
            processCaption(settings);
            $('.nivo-slice', slider).remove();
            $('.nivo-box', slider).remove();
            if (settings.effect == 'random') {
                var anims = new Array('sliceDownRight', 'sliceDownLeft', 'sliceUpRight', 'sliceUpLeft', 'sliceUpDown', 'sliceUpDownLeft', 'fold', 'fade', 'boxRandom', 'boxRain', 'boxRainReverse', 'boxRainGrow', 'boxRainGrowReverse');
                vars.randAnim = anims[Math.floor(Math.random() * (anims.length + 1))];
                if (vars.randAnim == undefined)
                    vars.randAnim = 'fade';
            }
            if (settings.effect.indexOf(',') != -1) {
                var anims = settings.effect.split(',');
                vars.randAnim = anims[Math.floor(Math.random() * (anims.length))];
                if (vars.randAnim == undefined)
                    vars.randAnim = 'fade';
            }
            vars.running = true;
            if (settings.effect == 'sliceDown' || settings.effect == 'sliceDownRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownRight' || settings.effect == 'sliceDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownLeft') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if (settings.effect == 'sliceDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownLeft')
                    slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider)._reverse();
                slices.each(function() {
                    var slice = $(this);
                    slice.css({
                        'top' : '0px'
                    });
                    if (i == settings.slices - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed, '', function() {
                                slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                            });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'sliceUp' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpRight' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpLeft') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if (settings.effect == 'sliceUpLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpLeft')
                    slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider)._reverse();
                slices.each(function() {
                    var slice = $(this);
                    slice.css({
                        'bottom' : '0px'
                    });
                    if (i == settings.slices - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed, '', function() {
                                slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                            });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'sliceUpDown' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDown' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDownLeft') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var v = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if (settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDownLeft')
                    slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider)._reverse();
                slices.each(function() {
                    var slice = $(this);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        slice.css('top', '0px');
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        slice.css('bottom', '0px');
                        i = 0;
                    }
                    if (v == settings.slices - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed, '', function() {
                                slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                            });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                height : '100%',
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    v++;
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'fold' || vars.randAnim == 'fold') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                $('.nivo-slice', slider).each(function() {
                    var slice = $(this);
                    var origWidth = slice.width();
                    slice.css({
                        top : '0px',
                        height : '100%',
                        width : '0px'
                    });
                    if (i == settings.slices - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                width : origWidth,
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed, '', function() {
                                slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                            });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            slice.animate({
                                width : origWidth,
                                opacity : '1.0'
                            }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'fade' || vars.randAnim == 'fade') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var firstSlice = $('.nivo-slice:first', slider);
                firstSlice.css({
                    'height' : '100%',
                    'width' : slider.width() + 'px'
                });
                firstSlice.animate({
                    opacity : '1.0'
                }, (settings.animSpeed * 2), '', function() {
                    slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'slideInRight' || vars.randAnim == 'slideInRight') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var firstSlice = $('.nivo-slice:first', slider);
                firstSlice.css({
                    'height' : '100%',
                    'width' : '0px',
                    'opacity' : '1'
                });
                firstSlice.animate({
                    width : slider.width() + 'px'
                }, (settings.animSpeed * 2), '', function() {
                    slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'slideInLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'slideInLeft') {
                createSlices(slider, settings, vars);
                var firstSlice = $('.nivo-slice:first', slider);
                firstSlice.css({
                    'height' : '100%',
                    'width' : '0px',
                    'opacity' : '1',
                    'left' : '',
                    'right' : '0px'
                });
                firstSlice.animate({
                    width : slider.width() + 'px'
                }, (settings.animSpeed * 2), '', function() {
                    firstSlice.css({
                        'left' : '0px',
                        'right' : ''
                    });
                    slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'boxRandom' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRandom') {
                createBoxes(slider, settings, vars);
                var totalBoxes = settings.boxCols * settings.boxRows;
                var i = 0;
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var boxes = shuffle($('.nivo-box', slider));
                boxes.each(function() {
                    var box = $(this);
                    if (i == totalBoxes - 1) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            box.animate({
                                opacity : '1'
                            }, settings.animSpeed, '', function() {
                                slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                            });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            box.animate({
                                opacity : '1'
                            }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 20;
                    i++;
                });
            } else if (settings.effect == 'boxRain' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRain' || settings.effect == 'boxRainReverse' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainReverse' || settings.effect == 'boxRainGrow' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainGrow' || settings.effect == 'boxRainGrowReverse' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainGrowReverse') {
                createBoxes(slider, settings, vars);
                var totalBoxes = settings.boxCols * settings.boxRows;
                var i = 0;
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var rowIndex = 0;
                var colIndex = 0;
                var box2Darr = new Array();
                box2Darr[rowIndex] = new Array();
                var boxes = $('.nivo-box', slider);
                if (settings.effect == 'boxRainReverse' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainReverse' || settings.effect == 'boxRainGrowReverse' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainGrowReverse') {
                    boxes = $('.nivo-box', slider)._reverse();
                }
                boxes.each(function() {
                    box2Darr[rowIndex][colIndex] = $(this);
                    colIndex++;
                    if (colIndex == settings.boxCols) {
                        rowIndex++;
                        colIndex = 0;
                        box2Darr[rowIndex] = new Array();
                    }
                });
                for (var cols = 0; cols < (settings.boxCols * 2); cols++) {
                    var prevCol = cols;
                    for (var rows = 0; rows < settings.boxRows; rows++) {
                        if (prevCol >= 0 && prevCol < settings.boxCols) {
                            (function(row, col, time, i, totalBoxes) {
                                var box = $(box2Darr[row][col]);
                                var w = box.width();
                                var h = box.height();
                                if (settings.effect == 'boxRainGrow' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainGrow' || settings.effect == 'boxRainGrowReverse' || vars.randAnim == 'boxRainGrowReverse') {
                                    box.width(0).height(0);
                                }
                                if (i == totalBoxes - 1) {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        box.animate({
                                            opacity : '1',
                                            width : w,
                                            height : h
                                        }, settings.animSpeed / 1.3, '', function() {
                                            slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished');
                                        });
                                    }, (100 + time));
                                } else {
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        box.animate({
                                            opacity : '1',
                                            width : w,
                                            height : h
                                        }, settings.animSpeed / 1.3);
                                    }, (100 + time));
                                }
                            })(rows, prevCol, timeBuff, i, totalBoxes);
                            i++;
                        }
                        prevCol--;
                    }
                    timeBuff += 100;
                }
            }
        }
        var shuffle = function(arr) {
            for (var j, x, i = arr.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x);
            return arr;
        }
        var trace = function(msg) {
            if (this.console && typeof console.log != "undefined")
                console.log(msg);
        }
        this.stop = function() {
            if (!$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop) {
                $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
                trace('Stop Slider');
            }
        }
        this.start = function() {
            if ($(element).data('nivo:vars').stop) {
                $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = false;
                trace('Start Slider');
            }
        }
        settings.afterLoad.call(this);
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.nivoSlider = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(key, value) {
            var element = $(this);
            if (element.data('nivoslider'))
                return element.data('nivoslider');
            var nivoslider = new NivoSlider(this, options);
            element.data('nivoslider', nivoslider);
        });
    };
    $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
        backgroundSize:'',
        effect : 'random',
        slices : 15,
        boxCols : 8,
        boxRows : 4,
        animSpeed : 500,
        pauseTime : 3000,
        startSlide : 0,
        directionNav : true,
        directionNavHide : true,
        controlNav : true,
        controlNavThumbs : false,
        controlNavThumbsFromRel : false,
        controlNavThumbsSearch : '.jpg',
        controlNavThumbsReplace : '_thumb.jpg',
        keyboardNav : true,
        pauseOnHover : true,
        manualAdvance : false,
        captionOpacity : 0.8,
        prevText : 'Prev',
        nextText : 'Next',
        beforeChange : function() {
        },
        afterChange : function() {
        },
        slideshowEnd : function() {
        },
        lastSlide : function() {
        },
        afterLoad : function() {
        }
    };
    $.fn._reverse = [].reverse;
})(jQuery); 

When you initial nivoSlide pass my new parameter backgroundSize:'your width size px your height size px';
Example: 
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
   backgroundSize:'687px 400px',
   effect: 'random',
   animSpeed: 500,
   pauseTime: 3000,
   directionNav: true,
   controlNav: true,
   controlNavThumbs: false,
   pauseOnHover: true});
});
```